# Set cookies only for exact subdomains and not for main domain

Tags: angular, cookies

I have main site and admin site. Main site and admin site share the same cookie. But I have such 2 sets of websites - 1 on main domain and other on subdomain. I do not want to access cookies between these sets.

E.g. I want to share cookie between

```
sandbox.billionlearners.com &
admin.sandbox.billionlearners.com
```

But I do not want to share it with main domain

```
billionlearners.com &
admin.billionlearners.com
```

If I set cookie domain as sandbox.billionlearners.com => main site (billionlearners.com) still can access it.

First of all is it technically possible ? Is there any workaround?

Would appreciate the inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour that cookie set for domain matches also for subdomains.

> `Domain=<domain-value>`
> Defines the host to which the cookie will be sent. If omitted, this attribute defaults to the host of the current document URL, not including subdomains. Contrary to earlier specifications, leading dots in domain names (.example.com) are ignored.
> Multiple host/domain values are not allowed, but if a domain is specified, then **subdomains are always included**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie#attributes

You could consider other storage methods aside from cookie? SessionStorage, LocalStorage...

Instead of using `domain` to tell them apart, use some other property e.g `name`?

Comment: thanks for the response, as I want to use same data on main site and admin site, I may not be able to use LocalStorage, but let me try with different "Name"